# Flex - How to pass parameters to a swf

Tags: apache-flex, flash, parameter-passing

I am using **FlashVars** to pass params in the swf but it is not working.

Here is the html code:

```
<noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="tpc">
            <param name="movie" value="tpc.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye">

            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="tpc.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                **<param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye">**

            <!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                <p> 
                    Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                    10.0.0 or greater is not installed.
                </p>
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </noscript>
```

Here is the .mxml file code:

```
            var keyStr:String;
            var valueStr:String;

            var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

            var length:int = 0;

            for (keyStr in paramObj) {
                length++;
            }

            if (length == 0) {
                ta.appendText("Length is zero so below is the dummy data:\n");
                paramObj = {test:"Test", test2:"Test2"};
            }

            for (keyStr in paramObj) {   
                valueStr = String(paramObj[keyStr]);
                ta.appendText("\t" + keyStr + ":\t" + valueStr + "\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use that HTML.  Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your Flash swf into your html.  It's easier to do and supported by Adobe.

Second, you're not accessing the vars properly and probably trying to access the vars too soon.  You need to wait for the application's creationComplete event before trying to access it.  There's a real good [tutorial on everything I just said on Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7feb.html).

Comment: +1 it worked... I am accessing the vars in init() function only which is called at application initialization time...applicationComplete="init()"

Answer (score 0):

Within the `<object>` try adding an `<embed>` like this:

```
<embed src="file.swf?myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye" width="" height="" />
```