# Flex - How to find all the published streams

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, netstream

I want to create two swf (publisher and subscriber).

I have created the publisher client which publishes the webcam video to the Red5 server.

Now I want to create the subscriber. I want some kind of combo box which lists all the streams being published at that moment. So that user can click on any of the stream name in the list to see that stream.

Q1. How the subscriber client can find all the published stream at that moment?

Q2. How the subscriber can update that list automatically (any events for which it can listen to so that it can add or delete stream from the list)?

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. How the subscriber client can find
>   all the published stream at that
>   moment?

Keep a running list on the server and have the client request it.

```
Q2. How the subscriber can update that list automatically (any events for which it can listen to so that it can add or delete stream from the list)?
```

You'll need to use a server side tool that supports push notifications.  LiveCycle and WebORB support this using RTMP.  BlazeDS and GraniteDS can support this using long polling.  I don't know if Red5 would offer any similar features; as I understand it's primary purpose is media delivery.

Comment: Is there any method which is called on the server whenever a stream is published to the server?

Comment: Could you please also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273759/flex-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-swf

Comment: "Is there any method which is called on the server whenever a stream is published to the server?" I assume so; but don't know.  Check the docs on that server.   The question you link to relates to FlashVars and I don't see how it relates to this question.